# Re-query a query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

For example, if I have this:

```
$user = User::where('color', 'red')
    ->get();
```

How can I query this variable, like:

```
$requery = $user->where('age', '25')
    ->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't invoke `get()` int the first place.

```
$user_query = User::where('color', 'red');
```

Now:

```
$users = $user_query->get(); // to get all color red
$users = $user_query->where('age', '25'); // to get all color red of age 25
```

`get()` performs the actual query. Until you invoke that method, you can keep modifying your query, adding to it, etc.

If you have performed the query already, that is invoked `get()`, and you no longer have a Laravel collection, but a normal array. You can create a new collection like this:

```
$users = collection($users);
```

With this can "filter" with the [where<sup>docs</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-where) method:

```
$users_of_age = collection($users)->where("age", 25);
```

I prefer that my models return a query rather than the actual items. That way you can modify the query in your controller, say for paging, or whatever.